How can there be two congruent curves (eg, $y=x^3$ and $y=x^{1/3}$), one smooth and the other not?
Consider the curve $$y = x^3  \tag{a}.$$  It is smooth, since all of its derivatives are defined and continuous.
Now consider a different curve, $$y = x^{1/3}  \tag{b}.$$  It is not smooth, since its first derivative, $y' = \frac 1 3 x^{-2/3}$, is discontinuous at $x = 0$.
However, the two curves are geometrically congruent!, as one is simply the reflection over $y = x$ of the other:

So we're left with a paradox: Two curves, congruent to each other, yet one smooth and the other not.  How do we resolve this?

The answer might be: We must not conflate smooth curve with smooth function.  It is true that (b) is not a smooth function, for the reason above.  But it is still a smooth curve, since it can be parameterized by a smooth function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$.  This answer, however, is incomplete. I presume that calling a function smooth indicates some type of geometric property, some type of, well, smoothness, and smoothness is presumably invariant under rigid motions.
In what manner, fit to be called "smooth", is curve (a) more smooth than (b)? What type of geometric property does the word smooth, as used in the term smooth function, convey?

Update
Inspired by David K's comment, I suggest the following.  It's a start: Perhaps someone could finish it, or opine if it's on the right track.

Continuous means: All changes, over a small enough range, are arbitrarily small.  Call this gradual.
Smooth means: All changes are gradual, and changes to the change are gradual, and changes to the change to...

Then (b) is a smooth curve, because, at any point, the vectors to neighbors are arbitrarily small, the changes to those vectors is arbitrarily small, and the change to the change of those vectors is arbitrarily small, etc.
However, (b) is not a smooth function, because, at $x = 0$, the rate of change of $y$ is unbound.  This doesn't affect the smoothness of the curve, because the unbound changes in $y$ happen over an inversely proportional small change in $x$, so neighbors are always near each other, and the vectors between them change gradually, and the differences in vectors change gradually, etc.
That is, if we ask "What happens to $y$ when we increase $x$?", our answer is unbound.  If we ask "What happens to the location of a neighbor as we move along the curve?" we get gradual changes ad infinitum.

You are right in that one should not get confused by the difference of "the curve" which is the image of a certain function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ in this case and the underlying function (parametrization) as the same curve can be obtained by different parametrizations. As far as I know a curve is called smooth if it admits a smooth parametrization. Your second curve is smooth since the parametrisation $t\mapsto (t^3,t)$ is.

While the derivative for the second curve is discontinuous at $x=0$, the left-hand limit and right-hand limit of $\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$ at $x=0$ are both equal to $+\infty$. Hence while the curve doesn't satisfy the conventional definition of a smooth function, it could be said to be a smooth curve. This is a consequence of the convention that functions cannot be a one-to-many mapping, but a curve (which is defined by a relation, not a function) can be many-to-one.

An even more astonishing contradiction: a horizontal line $y=0$ in a standard $OXY$ system of coordinates 'is' a function, which is continuous and even constant, whilst a congruent line $x=0$ 'is not' constant nor continuous, and not even a function! ;P Try to unravel this, then your original problem will become obvious.

There are two different things you are mixing: A curve (the geometric object, a subset of $\Bbb R^2$) and a parametrization of the curve which is a function. Unfortunately, those are often simply called "curve".

You start to get to the answer when you distinguish smooth curves from smooth functions. It's unclear to me if there's a really satisfying answer to the question of what geometric property is implied by the term "smooth function," since a function is not a geometric object. Note that of all the isometries of the graph of $y=x^3$ that leave $(0,0)$ fixed, there are only two (this one and its reflection across the $y$ axis) that produce the graph of a non-smooth function. The others are either smooth or not functions at all.

"since its first derivative, $y' = \frac 1 3 x^{-2/3}$, is discontinuous at $x = 0$" - no, it does not exist at $x=0$.

The update is a good answer to your question if I understand the question correctly.

To add to @frog's comment: the essential feature is not admitting a smooth parameterisation, but admitting one whose derivative is everywhere nonzero.
Consider a function like
$$
s(t) = \left(1-t\right)t^{2}+\ t\left(1\ \ -\ \left(t-1\right)^{2}\right)  
$$
for $ 0 \le t \le 1$,
which has $s(0) = 0, s(1) = 1, s'(0) = 0, $ and $s'(1) = 0$.
With this we can built
$$
Q(t) = \begin{cases}
(s(t), 0) & 0 \le t \le 1 \\
(1, s(t-1)) & 1 \le t \le 2\\
(1-s(t-2), 1) & 2 \le t \le 3\\
(0, 1-s(t-3)) & 3 \le t \le 4
\end{cases}
$$
which ends up being a smooth parameterization of the unit square. The problem is that the parameterization "slows down" at the corners so that the tangent is zero there, and adjacent segments can match up.
Once you insist that the tangent be everywhere nonzero, you get the condition you really wanted all along (at least locally --- you may also want to require that your function be injective to avoid "crossings" in your curve...or you may not).
Note: the particular function $s$ I constructed above is only $C^1$ smooth, I believe, but by defining
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp(\frac{-1}{x^2}) & x \ne 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
which has $h(0) = h'(0) = h''(0) = \ldots$, you can build up a $C^\infty$ version of the same thing, although it takes a little dancing around, and is really not the point of this answer.

You are right I should have made this more explicit. For me, a parametrization is already understood to be an injective immersion but this is of course to be mentioned.

Thanks.  You write that the tangent is zero at the corners.  It would seem to me that the tangent is undefined at the corners.  The velocity vector, with respect to $t$, is defined at the corners, and zero; everywhere else, the velocity vector is tangent.  So perhaps that would be a better choice.  Can you clarify?

That's a matter of whose definitions you use, but sure --- the velocity vector is zero at the corners. But that actually gives you $C^1$ continuity of the parameterization (or, if you go through the work of generalizing) $C^\infty$ continuity of the parameterization, i.e., it's a smooth parameterization of a "curve shape" in the plane that no one would call smooth. So "smooth parameterization" isn't enough. What is enough to get around this problem is "smooth parameterization with everywhere nonzero velocity vector".

In his comment, frog has sketched the solution.
Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. You say

Consider the curve  $y = f(x)$.

Unfortunately the concept of "curve" is a bit ambiguous. Wikipedia states

A curve is the image of an interval to a topological space by a continuous function. In some contexts, the function that defines the curve is called a parametrization, and the curve is a parametric curve.

Thus a curve in a space $X$ is a certain subset of $X$ and a parameterized (= parametric) curve is a continuous function $\gamma : J \to X$ where $J$ is an interval. BUT: Frequently the word "curve" is used as a synonym for "parameterized curve". This may be confusing indeed ...  in the sequel we shall therefore use precise notation.
Actually you consider the function $f(x)$, but this is not a curve in the plane. However, you can regard the set $G(f) = \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in \mathbb R\} \subset \mathbb R^2$, i.e. the graph of $f$, as a curve in the plane, although one which does not yet have a specific parameterization. The most "natural" parameterization is given by
$$\bar f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2, \bar f(x) = (x,f(x)) .$$
The right framework for your question is to consider parameterized curves
$$\gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2. $$
Such $\gamma$ is called smooth iff both coordinate functions $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are smooth. If $\gamma$ is smooth, then clearly also the reflected parameterized curve $\gamma^r(x) = (\gamma_2(x),\gamma_1(x))$ is smooth.
Thus, $f$ is smooth iff the parameterized curve $\bar f$ is smooth.
Does it make sense to call the curve $G(f)$ smooth? In other words, does it make sense to call a subset of the plane smooth? There is the concept of a smooth submanifold, and it is easy to show that $G(f)$ is a smooth one-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ iff the function $f$ is smooth. However, smoothness of $f$ is not a necessary condition for $G(f)$ to be a smooth submanifold. But let us not go into details. At the moment it makes more sense to ask whether a given curve in the plane has a smooth parameterization (which is not guaranteed).
Now consider the reflected curve (the blue curve in your figure) which is the set $G^r(f) = \{(f(x),x) \mid x \in \mathbb R \}$. An obvious parameterization is given by
$$\bar f^r: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2, \bar f^r(x) = (f(x),x) .$$
This is the reflected parameterized curve of $\bar f$ as considered above. Again we see that $f$ is smooth iff $\bar f^r$ is smooth.
However, $G^r(f)$ as well as $G(f)$ always have many other parameterizations which are not smooth.
In the special case that $f$ is a bijection, it is well-known that $f^{-1}:  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is also continuous so that $\tilde f(x) = (x,f^{-1}(x))$ is an alternative parameterization of $G^r(f)$. But if $f$ is smooth, then in general $f^{-1}$ is not smooth and $\tilde f$ is no smooth parameterization of $G^r(f)$. This happens in your example $f(x) = x^3$: The function $f^{-1}(x) = x^{\frac 1 3}$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.
Anyway, if $f$ is a smooth bijection which has non-vanishing derivative $f'$, then $f^{-1}$ is also smooth (recall that $(f^{-1})'(y) = \dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}$ in this case).

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $c$ be a map from an open subset of $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We call $c$ a chart at a point $x$ in $S$ if it is a bijection, is smooth and has a smooth inverse. We say that $S$ is a smooth curve at $x$ if there exists a chart at $x$.
The two curves you describe are both smooth. However, the map $(x,y)\mapsto x$ is a chart at the origin only for one of them (the first). More generally, a function is smooth if and only if this map is a chart for its graph.
